# google drive java library setting range header for downloads

Tags: java, download, google-drive-api, range

I'm downloading a file from Google Drive using their java client library and am trying to download only a part of the file at a time. I've tried setting the range header like so

```
Drive.Files.Get file = drive.files().get(fileId);
file.getRequestHeaders().setRange(String.format("bytes=%s-%s", byteRangeStart, byteRangeEnd));
file.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(oStream);
```

but it still downloads the whole file. I've found I can do

```
Drive.Files.Get file = drive.files().get(fileId);
file.getMediaHttpDownloader().setBytesDownloaded(byteRangeStart);
file.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(oStream);
```

instead which does correctly start downloading at a later point, but still downloads to the end of the file.
Lastly I tried using

```
file.getMediaHttpDownloader().setContentRange(byteRangeStart, (int) byteRangeEnd);
```

which has a twofold problem of not working and the second argument being an integer for some strange reason.

Any help would be appreciated!